# Qt QGraphicView клик мышью

Tags: qt

Есть QGraphicView, нужно при клике на него что-то делать, как это сделать?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, что у вас есть и лучше объясните, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: У меня есть форма, на ней QGraphicView, надо при клике мышью по QGraphicView выполнить функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) в классе формы.
object это виджет с которым что-то случилось,event это, то что случилось